# How many slots and tokens will AWS CloudHSM present to PKCS11 applications?

Tags: amazon-web-services

I'm using the Cavium-based AWS CloudHSM and I'm trying to figure out how the HSMs are presented to applications through the PKCS #11 library.

From my experimentation, it seems like the library offers only one slot and token to the application, regardless of the number of HSMs available. However, I was hoping someone could confirm this (and thus rule out misconfiguration on my part). I'm assuming this is a load-balanced slot that will share work between the HSMs.

For the experiment, I commissioned two HSMs in a cluster and configured my EC2 instance using these commands:

```
sudo /opt/cloudhsm/bin/configure -a <IP address of HSM 1>
sudo start cloudhsm-client
sudo /opt/cloudhsm/bin/configure -m  // which I think informs it of the second HSM
```

If I run the [`getHSMInfo`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cloudhsm/latest/userguide/cloudhsm_mgmt_util-getHSMInfo.html) command I see two HSMs. However, when I inspect the PKCS #11 slot configuration, there is only one slot (and its `serial num` field corresponds to the first HSM).

Can anyone confirm how this ought to work?

<sub>(NB: I've raised an issue on the docs requesting more clarity [here](https://github.com/awsdocs/aws-cloudhsm-user-guide/issues/7)).</sub>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is correct.  An entire cluster will show up as a single slot and single token.

In terms of load balancing:

Any token keys created will be replicated across all of the HSMs in the cluster; any session keys will only exist on a single HSM.

Any operations on token keys will be load-balanced across the HSMs in the cluster, but session key operations won't be due to the session keys only existing on a single device.

Comment: An interesting situation that can come up due to session keys not being replicated, is that if you create one and then attempt to use it, you might get load balanced to another HSM in your cluster and it won't be able to find the key. Unfortunately there isn't a way to control the load balancing, so AWS support recommended persisting it on the device instead to have it replicate, I then have to manually delete it after I'm done with it.